# How to list the target path of all My Network Places in vbs?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I want a script to list a users My Network Places in Windows XP. There are lots of examples on the web that show how to get the *Name* of each location, but I want the target path (i.e. the server name / folder that the link is pointing at).

To get the name I can do:

```
Const MY_NETWORK_PLACES = &H12&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(MY_NETWORK_PLACES)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
Next
```

How do I get the target path? Looking at .Path gives me the local path of the shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.GetLink.Path`:

```
If objItem.IsFileSystem Then
   Wscript.Echo objItem.Name, " =>", objItem.GetLink.Path
End If
```